# asp.net How To allow only one Domain user

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis-7, web-config

I have looked for this issue on the internet and nothing specifies how to solve my problem.
It is a very small web application hosted on IIS7. In my web.config i have this code:

```
<system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="WORKGROUP\SOMEONE"/>
        <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
```

When i access my website, it gives me the following error

```
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
```

I want to authenticate only one domain user and I think i have used everything correctly. Please Guide Me What am i missing here

Comment: Don't you need to add `<authentication mode="Windows"/>` and also turn on Windows Auth in IIS?

Comment: how do i turn on Windows Auth in IIS??

Comment: Go to the site/application you want in in "Features View" double click on Authentication. You should see all supported types there. You'll want to disable Anonymous and enable Windows.

Comment: Dear I only see Form Authentication, Anonymous Authentication and ASP.NET Impersonation which are all disabled. I don't see any Windows There

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to install Windows Authentication and enable that on the IIS website.

See this post for details on how to install and configure Windows Authentication on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008R2: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication